# Can't pass paremeters using KOA-NEO4J library

Tags: node.js, neo4j, koa

I am trying to create a REST API which connects to a NEO4J instance. I am using the koa-neo4j library as the basis (https://github.com/assister-ai/koa-neo4j-starter-kit).

This first example below works fine. When I hit the endpoint "myapp/metric" I get the expected result back from the database.

**Index.js**

```
//Return all metrics from the database
app.defineAPI({
    method: 'GET',
    route: '/api/v1/imm/metric',
    cypherQueryFile: './src/api/v1/imm/metric/metric.cyp'
});
```

**metric.cyp**

```
MATCH (a:metric)
RETURN a AS metric
```

I am trying to build on this example creating an endpoint where I can pass a parameter that will be used in the cypher query I have followed the documentation and ended up with the below.

**Index.js**

```
//Return all metrics from the database matching a specific metric name
app.defineAPI({
    method: 'GET',
    route: '/api/v1/imm/metric/:metricname',
    cypherQueryFile: './src/api/v1/imm/metric/metric-by-name.cyp'
});
```

**metric-by-name.cyp**

```
MATCH (a:metric {name: $metricname })
RETURN a AS metric
```

When I hit the endpoint "myapp/metric/TestMetricName" I just get an error message back which is coming from Neo4j.

> ConflictError: error while executing Cypher: Error: Variable
>   `$metricname` not defined (line 1, column 24 (offset: 23)) "MATCH
>   (a:metric {name: $metricname })"

It looks like the code is not swapping out the placeholder $metricname in the cypher query for the value that I have passed (e.g. TestMetricName).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What version of `neo4j` you use?

Comment: Neo4j Community Edition 3.0.5 running on GrapheneDB.com

Comment: Try `{metricname}` instead `$metricname`

Comment: I get the same result --> ConflictError: error while executing Cypher: Error: Variable `metricname` not defined (line 1, column 24 (offset: 23))
"MATCH (a:metric {name: metricname })"

Comment: Sorry - my bad. I had replaced $metricname with metricname instad of {metricname} as you suggested (e.g. I missed the curly brackets when I first made the change). Its working perfectly now so thanks a lot. Do you know if the documentation is outdated or was I just missing something by including the $ at first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 3.1.10-M06 new syntax for parameters in Cypher ($param instead of {param}). The documentation and example for the library `koa-Neo4j` uses the latest version.

So try `{param}` instead `$param`.

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-3.1-changelog#310-m06

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/7558